# Java Android FCM parse data to object

Tags: java, android

I want to parse json which I send to my phone. this is what I get :

In params I get two string

```
UPDATE_ROUTE
```

and

```
 [{"card_id":"3a296050-b7dc-4f7b-a041-162817090520","t_tasks_e_dic_load_types_sj_id":132,"status_id":2,"eup":"86baeff7e","card_nr":"211","change_time":"2019-12-17T12:04:43.129Z"}]
```

this is my class :

```
public class FCMResponse{
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<DataItem> data;


    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
}
```

I try do this :

```
 FCMResponse fcm = g.fromJson("\"data\":"+updateResponse.getData(), FCMResponse.class);
```

but when I try parse this or try parse string to my java class I get :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this response,

```
[{"card_id":"3a296050-b7dc-4f7b-a041-162817090520","t_tasks_e_dic_load_types_sj_id":132,"status_id":2,"eup":"86baeff7e","card_nr":"211","change_time":"2019-12-17T12:04:43.129Z"}]
```

your model class should be

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("card_id")
    @Expose
    private String cardId;
    @SerializedName("t_tasks_e_dic_load_types_sj_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId;
    @SerializedName("status_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer statusId;
    @SerializedName("eup")
    @Expose
    private String eup;
    @SerializedName("card_nr")
    @Expose
    private String cardNr;
    @SerializedName("change_time")
    @Expose
    private String changeTime;

    public String getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }

    public void setCardId(String cardId) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
    }

    public Integer getTTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId() {
        return tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId;
    }

    public void setTTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId(Integer tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId) {
        this.tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId = tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId;
    }

    public Integer getStatusId() {
        return statusId;
    }

    public void setStatusId(Integer statusId) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
    }

    public String getEup() {
        return eup;
    }

    public void setEup(String eup) {
        this.eup = eup;
    }

    public String getCardNr() {
        return cardNr;
    }

    public void setCardNr(String cardNr) {
        this.cardNr = cardNr;
    }

    public String getChangeTime() {
        return changeTime;
    }

    public void setChangeTime(String changeTime) {
        this.changeTime = changeTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example{" +
                "cardId='" + cardId + '\'' +
                ", tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId=" + tTasksEDicLoadTypesSjId +
                ", statusId=" + statusId +
                ", eup='" + eup + '\'' +
                ", cardNr='" + cardNr + '\'' +
                ", changeTime='" + changeTime + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And you can fetch in class like,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Example[] examples = gson.fromJson(response, Example[].class);
Example example = examples[0];
```